# MySQL slave replicates changes that are in neither binlog_do_db nor replicate_do_db

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a standard simple master slave replication that usually runs fine.
But sometimes, all of a sudden, I get replication errors on the "phpmyadmin" table.

I have explicitly only specified one database in `replicate_do_db` and in `binlog_do_db`. So it should only log and process that database. Why am I getting errors on another table?

This is the output of master status and slave status:

```
mysql> show master status \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
            File: mysql-bin.001473
        Position: 84364707
    Binlog_Do_DB: my-database
Binlog_Ignore_DB: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
mysql> show slave status \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: my-master-host
                  Master_User: pm-rep
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.001473
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 82124707
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000486
                Relay_Log_Pos: 38975372
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.001473
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB: my-database
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 1146
                   Last_Error: Error 'Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_column_info' doesn't exist' on query. Default database: 'my-database'. Query: 'DELETE FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma_column_info` WHERE `db_name` = 'my-database' AND `table_name` = 'users' AND `column_name` = 'INDEX''
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 38975226
              Relay_Log_Space: 82125053
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 1146
               Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_column_info' doesn't exist' on query. Default database: 'my-database'. Query: 'DELETE FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma_column_info` WHERE `db_name` = 'my-database' AND `table_name` = 'users' AND `column_name` = 'INDEX''
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 5309510
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

Replication filtering isn't bulletproof. Due to how the filtering is implemented the events responsible for your errors are being generated because the default database at query runtime is the `my-database` schema as expected and the query being executed is fully qualified `INSERT INTO phpmyadmin.pma_column_info`...

Peter Zaitsev explains the scenario well in this post:

[Filtered MySQL Replication](http://www.percona.com/blog/2007/11/07/filtered-mysql-replication/)

Answer (score 1):

This problem might have occurred because of the phpmyadmin version difference in master and slave. Due to the difference one creates one table with single `_` (underscore) i.e., `phpmyadmin.pma_recent` and the other with two `__` (underscores) i.e., `phpmyadmin.pma__recent`.

But as we just require some main database to replicate we can ignore these conflicts by adding the following lines.

Edit in `my.cnf` file by the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf

replicate-ignore-table=phpmyadmin.pma_recent
replicate-ignore-table=phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs
replicate-ignore-table=phpmyadmin.pma_column_info
//mention whichever table is throwing error
```

Then,

- restart mysql
- stop slave
- start slave
- show slave status

...and the error should be gone.

Comment: Welcome on the DBA SE! Why is it so?

Comment: this problem might occurred  because of the phpmyadmin version difference in master and slave..and due to the difference one create table with single _ i.e., phpmyadmin.pma_recent and other with two __ phpmyadmin.pma__recent. But as we just require some main database to replicate we can ingore these conflicts by adding above lines.

Comment: Thanks! I did not ask it for myself, but because there is a requirement, that answers should be understable and useful without the comments. I tried to insert your comment into the post. Such high quality answers get upvotes. :-)